# MySQL case statement help - getting multiple columns

Tags: mysql, case

I've written a series of two related case statements (x4 scenarios), and because of the way the raw data is set up, I'm getting two duplicate rows per unique ID. I'm generate an individual row for the columns ladder_name and ladder_value, when actually they are related to each other and should only be generated in combination.

I'm not sure how to adjust the case statement to only get one row per unique ID.

CODE:

```
    SELECT 
    # overall 
        sc.salesforce_id,
    # first trigger
        member_id_lh1, 
        ladder_config_id_lh1, 
        trigger_name_lh1,
        trigger_record_id_lh1, 
        date_trigger_event_lh1,
        ladder_name_lh1,
        ladder_value_lh1,
        ladder_change_lh1,
    # second trigger 
        member_id_lh2, 
        trigger_name_lh2,
        trigger_record_id_lh2, 
        date_trigger_event_lh2,
        ladder_name_lh2,
        ladder_value_lh2,
        ladder_change_lh2,
        days_spent,
        rank,
    # regions
        #placeholder for now 
    #demographics
        ar.`name` as alumni_region_name,
        gender,
        is_parent,
        is_teacher,
        first_generation_american,
        first_generation_college_going,
        lgbtq,
        veteran,
        person_of_color,
        low_income_background,
        registered_to_vote,
        contact_in_ri_supported_region,
        ethnicity,
    # current ladder level
        ladder_engagement as current_engagement_level,
        ladder_advocacy as current_advocacy_level,
        ladder_elected as current_elected_level,
        ladder_policy as current_policy_level,
        ladder_organizing as current_organizing_level,
        ladder_collective as current_collective_level,
    # Count - gain and loss
        case 
            when (ladder_value_lh2 > ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null) then 1
                else -1 
            end as moved_up_down,
    #referring ladder level
        case 
            when ladder_value_lh2 > ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null then ladder_name_lh2 
                else ladder_name_lh1 
            end as gain_moved_to_from_ladder_name,
        case 
            when ladder_value_lh2 > ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null then ladder_value_lh2 
                else ladder_value_lh1 
            end as gain_moved_to_from_ladder_level,
        case 
            when ladder_value_lh2 < ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null then ladder_name_lh2 
                else ladder_name_lh1 
            end as loss_moved_to_from_ladder_name, 
        case 
            when ladder_value_lh2 < ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null then ladder_value_lh2 
                else ladder_value_lh1 
            end as loss_moved_to_from_ladder_level, 
    #referring trigger level 
        case 
            when ladder_value_lh2 > ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null then trigger_name_lh2 
                else trigger_name_lh1 
            end as gain_moved_to_from_trigger_name,
        case 
            when ladder_value_lh2 > ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null then ladder_value_lh2 
                else ladder_value_lh1 
            end as gain_moved_to_from_trigger_level,
        case 
            when ladder_value_lh2 < ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null then trigger_name_lh2 
                else trigger_name_lh1 
            end as loss_moved_to_from_trigger_name, 
        case 
            when ladder_value_lh2 < ladder_value_lh1 and ladder_value_lh2 is not null then ladder_value_lh2 
                else ladder_value_lh1 
            end as loss_moved_to_from_trigger_level

    from leeds_new.salesforce_contacts as sc
        inner join cte_ladder_history_join_lh1_lh2_current_trigger_record on sc.salesforce_id = cte_ladder_history_join_lh1_lh2_current_trigger_record.member_id_lh1
        inner join leeds_new.salesforce_alumni_regions_federated as ar on sc.alumni_region_id = ar.alumni_region_id;
```

RESULTS: 
[image]

Comment: Your duplicates have to come from one of your INNER JOIN`s. Are those 1-1 relationships ?

Comment: why dont you use `select distinct`. IF both rows are exactly same it works

Comment: ah. salesforce_id = member_id_lh1 also has the same field member_id_lh2 from the third temporary table. I bet that is what is happening.

Comment: @Simonare for select distinct, which cols will it use to determine what is distinct? The first cols listed? Or is a combination of all the cols together?

Comment: @AlissaSwartz It's all the listed columns.

Comment: ah. i think this is working for me -- thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both rows are exactly same (which seems like that), you can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

clause for dedublication.